# Is possible to connect to Windows Machine via PHP?

Tags: php, windows

I want to write a PHP script that connects to a network PC's C drive: \MAINPC\C$ and then authenticates itself (I provide the username and password) and then iterate over the file in another folder. The iterating part is easy, but I am stuck as to what to use to actually connect to the Windows server or whether or not I would have to use some low-level socket connection?

Comment: Gud Question. For that you have to go for Java PHP Bridge . http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/  Because Only php is not abel to that type of connection .

Comment: You need to find and use an SMB (Samba) client in PHP. Google will give you results.

Comment: But does that mean I must install Samba on all the PCs I wish to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

There is this:

[stream wrapper to access Windows shared files](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4129-PHP-Stream-wrapper-to-access-Windows-shared-files.html)

It wraps the smbclient program.

[Further discussion in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768333/php-samba-smb-cifs-and-smb4php-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount network shares to device names in windows, or simply mount them to a directory (via smb) on linux.

Then to php it is a simple file operation. You will have to make sure that the share is up tho.

Comment: Thing is, this script will iterate over several machines to do varios custom updates. I wanted to do it in PHP, because the logic for the calculation is done in PHP, so it would be two birds with one stone.

Comment: No it would not. PHP is not the best solution to do this. you know it was once called "Pretty Home Pages" and that is what you should use it for. Use the right tool for the job!

Comment: @GungFoo: This last argument really has no merit.

Comment: @Jon look at the garbage collection problems STILL (after years of development) existing with PHP.

Comment: @GungFoo: I don't know what you are referring to, and it doesn't matter anyway. With the same logic more than half of the PHP extensions should never have been developed because well, what do you need e.g. image processing for? Pretty Home Page, right?

Comment: Okay, what is the best tool for the job then? Java?

Comment: This topic has been the basis for endless flamewars so i will not pursue this. All i am saying is that PHP is an interpreted script language and therefore has performance bottlenecks/problems and should not be used for anything more complex than PHP Hypertext Preprocessing. Don't use a hammer to put a screw into the wall!

Comment: @RD smbmount the directory... with system() from php if you must. ;) But leave PHP out of connecting to a windoze share. It will only allocate needlessly large amounts of memory and most likely also refuse to let go of it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot magically access data on another machine.

You need a server on that machine (here the windows PC) that serves the file system you are interested in. Then you can create a php script that accesses the content of the filesystem by using that server.

Actually there are ready-to-use components for that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Is the webserver on a linux/unix-box?

Are the machines on the same LAN?

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html may help you.

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same lan.